# How to change the dimensions of the graphs output in the grid.arrange() function in R?

Tags: r, function

I would like to make the output graphs wider. How do I accomplish this with the grid.arrange() function?

I have 4 scatter plots but they are a bit scrunched when I run the function. I just simply want to increase their width so they aren't scrunched and the values on the x axis read cleanly.

Can I easily manipulate dimensions with the grid.arrange() function?

I tried width()...but that didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Sam Donato, could you please share your code and data usign `dput(data)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.